# Pyopengl giving me Value error not able to identify the problem

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

I am getting started with opengl in python and i have the exact same code like that of the youtuber's , but it gives me an error :

```
pygame 1.9.6 Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/python files/Opengl/Opengl_cheatsheet.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()   File "C:/python files/Opengl/Opengl_cheatsheet.py", line 61, in main
    cube()   File "C:/python files/Opengl/Opengl_cheatsheet.py", line 39, in cube
    glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])   File "src/latebind.pyx", line 39, in OpenGL_accelerate.latebind.LateBind.__call__
    File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 299, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__
    File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 161, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.PyArgCalculator.c_call
    File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 128, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.PyArgCalculatorElement.c_call
    File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 114, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.PyArgCalculatorElement.c_call
    File "src/arraydatatype.pyx", line 419, in OpenGL_accelerate.arraydatatype.AsArrayTypedSizeChecked.c_call
    ValueError: ('Expected 12 byte array, got 8 byte array', (-1, 0), None)
```

And here is my code :

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

#vertices for the cube tuples
vertices = ((1, -1, -1),
            (1, 1, -1),
            (-1, 1 -1),
            (-1, -1, -1),
            (1, -1, 1),
            (1, 1, 1),
            (-1, -1, 1),
            (-1, 1, 1),
            )

#edge for the cube tuples
edges = ((0,1),
         (0,3),
         (0,4),
         (2,1),
         (2,3),
         (2,7),
         (6,3),
         (6,4),
         (6,7),
         (5,1),
         (5,4),
         (5,7),
         )


def cube():

    glBegin(GL_LINES)

    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
            
    
    glEnd()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (800, 800)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)
    glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 0)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        cube()
        pygame.display.flip()

        pygame.time.wait(10)

main()
```

---

Comment: It is a typo. A `,` is missing in `vertices`. (3rd vertex)

Comment: ohhhhh , such a silly mistake !!!!

Comment: Silly or not, Thanks! I had displaced parentheses in a long array, which led me here.

Comment: Nice it helped you @Joshua Clayton

Answer (score 1):

It is a typo. A `,` is missing in the list of vertices. (3rd vertex):

> ```py
> vertices = ((1, -1, -1),
>            (1, 1, -1),
>            (-1, 1 -1),         # <-------
>            (-1, -1, -1),
>            (1, -1, 1),
>            (1, 1, 1),
>            (-1, -1, 1),
>            (-1, 1, 1),
>            )
> ```